# how to make my Calculator with tkinter calculate everything in the Entry?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, eval

so i wanted to make a simple calculator with tkinter, but got stuck in a issue. and the issue is that i don't really know how to make tkinter take everything from the entry calculate it and that ouputs it in the same entry. everytime i try to save everything that the user inputs in the entry in a variable (i do this by trying to save the text from function set_text) either i get a name error = (NameError: name 'data_from_entry' is not defined)(even when i use 
global data_from_entry) or it only saves the last part of the users input(i thing this happens because the text in the function set_text changes everytime i click another button, so at the end it only has the last string that i use)

i also tried calculating with eval, but that also didn't work.

so here's my code, feel free to copy it and modify anything u want, all tips are welcome

```
'''from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator')
root.iconbitmap('abc.ico') #my icon

HEIGHT = 530
WIDTH = 325

canvas = Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()


frame1 = Frame(root, bg='#BEBDB8', bd=5)
frame1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.3, anchor='n')

entry1 = Entry(frame1, bg='#BEBDB8')
entry1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, relwidth=0.97, relheight=0.97, anchor='n')
entry1.config(font=("Courier", 44))


def CombinedFunctions(): # i use this so i can give a button multiply commands
    set_text('')
    Result()


global text2 # now text2 is not a local variable anymore

def set_text(text):
    entry1.insert(END, text)
    text2 =''
    text2 = str(text) # tryna save the text in text2 so it's easier and so i make sure it's a string
global data # global again
data = ''
data = data + text2
def Result():
    print(str(data)) # here im using just print to check if the real problem is eval or just my bad #code skills
    #calculate = str(eval(str(data))) #here is where i tried eval
    #entry1.delete(0, END)
    #entry1.insert(0, calculate)







#global database2, database     

#def Database(text):                   # some other things i tried
#   database2 = ""
#   database2 = database2 + database  


def delete():
    entry1.delete(0, END)   # deleting strings with the delete button


frame2 = Frame(root, bg='#BEBDB8', bd=5)
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.7)

button1 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=1, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(1))
button1.place(relx=0.015, rely=0, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button2 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=2, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(2))
button2.place(relx=0.270, rely=0, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button3 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=3, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(3))
button3.place(relx=0.525, rely=0, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button_delete = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='<-', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: delete())
button_delete.place(relx=0.77, rely=0, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button4 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=4, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(4))
button4.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.160, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button5 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=5, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(5))
button5.place(relx=0.270, rely=0.160, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button6 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=6, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(6))
button6.place(relx=0.525, rely=0.160, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button_multiply = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='x', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text('*'))
button_multiply.place(relx=0.77, rely=0.160, relwidth=0.105, relheight=0.150)

button_devide = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=':', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(':'))
button_devide.place(relx=0.89, rely=0.160, relwidth=0.105, relheight=0.150)

button7 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=7, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(7))
button7.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.320, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button8 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=8, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(8))
button8.place(relx=0.270, rely=0.320, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button9 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=9, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(9))
button9.place(relx=0.525, rely=0.320, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button_add = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='+', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text('+'))
button_add.place(relx=0.77, rely=0.320, relwidth=0.105, relheight=0.150)

button_minus = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='-', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text('-'))
button_minus.place(relx=0.89, rely=0.320, relwidth=0.105, relheight=0.150)

button_date = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='date', font=('Courier', 20), command=lambda: set_text('you forgot this'))
button_date.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.480, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button0 = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=0, font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text(0))
button0.place(relx=0.270, rely=0.480, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button_float = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text=',', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: set_text('.'))
button_float.place(relx=0.525, rely=0.480, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)

button_result = Button(frame2, bg='#D9DDDC', relief='flat', activebackground='#BEBDB8', text='=', font=('Courier', 30), command=lambda: CombinedFunctions()) # here i call the combinedfunction which calls #other 2 functions
button_result.place(relx=0.77, rely=0.480, relwidth=0.225, relheight=0.150)'''
```

any help is welcome :)

Comment: A `global` declaration at the top level of your code is *utterly pointless* - I have absolutely no idea why Python even allows that.  The place where `global` actually works is inside each function that contains an assignment to the variable, as that assignment would otherwise make the variable local to the function.

Comment: @jasonharper how should i use this comment to get the result that i want???

Answer (score 0):

you should use eval() expression like this (with a string inside)

```py
x='56*78'
eval(x)

# 4368
```